# find the upper bound on a vector

Tags: vector-analysis

I have a vector $R$ which from previous work I found it to be equal to $\frac{1}{2}f''(x+a(y-x))(y-x)^2b$ where $a\in(0,b)$ and $x,y\in\Re^d$.

I am also given that $\|R\|_2\le$$L\|x-y\|^2_2$ and I have to find this constant L.  Therefore I decided to find an upper bound on R but I do not know how. I need some help

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are vectors in $\Re^d$ then what it means$(y-x)^2$?

Comment: Initially I had a function $g(b)=f_i(x+b(y-x))$ and the second derivative is what I gave you.

Comment: It is given that $b\in\Re$

Comment: Their function $f$ has all the partial derivatives of second order $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}f(x) $continuous to $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$?

Comment: Yes, it has all the partial derivatives of second order continuous to x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, since $f$ is $C^2$ class, you can use development of Taylor and the mean value theorem for functions of several variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$. But it would be too much work.  I believe the solution below is easier.

**Hint:** The secret is to understand that the second derivative of $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ as a bililinear transformation
$$
\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d\ni(u.v)\longmapsto D^{(2)}f(p)\bullet(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^d 
$$
and then applying an important property of the matrices: if $v$ is a column vector and $M$ a square matrix then  $\|Mv\|\leq \sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}^d}\|Mz\|\cdot \|v\|$.
Then 
\begin{align}
\|bD^{(2)}f(p)\bullet (u,v)\|
\leq
&
\left(\sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\|bD^{(2)}f(p)\bullet (z,v)\|}{\|z\|}\right)\|u\|
\\
\leq
&
\left(\sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}^d}\sup_{w\in\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\|bD^{(2)}f(p)\bullet (z,w)\|}{\|z\|\|w\|}\right)\|u\|\|v\|
\\
\leq
&
\left(\sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}^d}\sup_{w\in\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\|D^{(2)}f(p)\bullet (z,w)\|}{\|z\|\|w\|}\right)b\|u\|\|v\|
\end{align}
Set $p= x+a(y-x)$ and $u=v=(y-x)$ to obtain the desired result.

Comment: is it possible to show me the solution using Taylor and the mean value theorem for functions of several variables taking values in $R^d$ as you said initially ??

Comment: @user189013 yes, if $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is $C^r$ for $r\geq 2$.